# On centos 8 How to create a bridge after a vlan?

Tags: centos, kvm, bridge, vlan

I have a centos8 computer connected to a switch with a vlan tag.
I want to create a virtual network  like this :

vlan network 
[image: vlan network]

I need to tag/untag on physical interface only.

I successfully create a vlan interface named `eno3.10` ( vlanid = 10) but when i create the bridge i am stuck.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I post a solution that i found:

Create vlan based bridge

nmcli con add type bridge autoconnect yes con-name bridge20 ifname bridge20 bridge.stp no

Configure ip for the virtual bridges

nmcli con modify bridge20 ipv4.addresses 192.168.0.1/24 ipv4.method manual

Add a vlan to the bridges:

nmcli con add type vlan autoconnect yes con-name vlan20 dev eno3 id 200 master bridge20

Turn on the bridges

nmcli con up bridge20